# Equiconuity in extended sense

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a sequence of step functions $\{f_n(t), t\geq 0\}$ where each function is a one step left shift of the previous function. So, $f_{n+1}(t) = f_{n}(t + x_n)$ where $x_n$ is the first time when the first jump occurs for the function $f_n$. The subsequent jumps are at the time $x_{n+1} + x_{n}, x_{n+2} +x_{n+1} + x_{n}, \dots$ and so on for the function $f_n$ . Also, it is given that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ decreases to zero. Clearly, $f_n$'s are not continuous. But, can we say that $\forall \epsilon >0$ there exist $\delta$ such that $\forall x,y $ with $|x-y| < \delta$

$$\limsup_{n} |f_n(x) - f_n(y)| < \epsilon$$

The previous condition is called equicontinuity in the extended sense.

Comment: I'm sorry is not clear, at least to me, what is $x_n$

Comment: I think we would need more information about these $f(t)$ functions

Comment: @rlartiga: $x_n(>0)$ is the time for first jump of the function $f_n$. first time of jump is different for different functions.

Comment: What happen when you shift to the negative side?

Comment: @rlartiga: time is always non-negative

Comment: $$f_1(t)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^m \alpha_i \chi_{A_i}(t)$$

Where $A_i$ are disjoints intervals of the form $[a_i,a_i+ L_i]$. Then $x_1=a_1$ so:

$$f_2(t)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^m \alpha_i \chi_{A_i}(t+a_1)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^m \alpha_i \chi_{A_i^2}(t)$$

Where $A_i^2=[a_i-a_1,a_i+L_i-a_1]$, so $x_2=a_2-a_1$:

$$f_3(t)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^m \alpha_i \chi_{A_i^2}(t+a_2-a_1)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^m \alpha_i \chi_{A_i^3}(t)$$

Where $A_i^3=[a_i-a_2,a_i+L_i-a_2]$ **here** because are you left shifting you are allowing to pass to other side.

Comment: @rlartiga: Then make it zero. The functions $f_n$ for all $n$ is always on the positive side of the $x$-axis. In the negative side it is zero .